# What is the most efficient way to use Git for a version control beginner, UI Application or Terminal?

Tags: git

I'm looking to start using Git and I just wanted to know what is the best practice. Is a IDE based application better over the terminal based one on MacOS? I do like the sound of a IDE based application, but I'm just wondering what would be the best practice option.

Comment: What do you mean by "UI based"? The terminal is a user interface.

Comment: Your question invites opinion and yet is interesting, so I'll comment.  I actually use both and I recommend both.  When I need fine grain precision over what I'm doing, I use the command line, which is very powerful.  When I need to _see_ what I'm doing, e.g. a branch diagram, then I go for a UI tool.  What I would _not_ recommend doing is _only_ using the UI tool.  You will never get a visceral understanding of the Git commands.

Comment: @melpomene The OP probably means using SourceTree or maybe a Git plugin in an IDE.  This in contrast to doing everything from the command line bash.

Comment: Git is fundamentally a command-line tool.  If you come here asking git questions in the future, people are going to provide you with instructions involving the command line, rather than whatever specific UI you're familiar with.  Regardless of what you end up using as your development environment you should become familiar with `git`.

Comment: The question of whether a GUI or the cli is "better" isn't really one we can answer for you.  You'll have to make that decision yourself based on your experience and your needs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'll flag this question as *primarily opinion-based*, as answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: If you'd like to master Git, start from the command line. GUIs hide too many details, which prevents you from learning deep.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Learning git is the same whether you use terminal or ui application  - you still need to know what's going on.  Once you know what's going on then it doesn't matter what you use but i find the terminal easier for everything except visualising branches.

I'd recommend starting with the terminal to type commands but also using a ui application so you can visualise what's going on - it was inordinately helpful to me in learning git basics.

In terms of efficiency in learning using both the terminal and ui application worked for me.